# How to pass an enum parameter from a loop?

Tags: typescript, enums

Consider the code below.  I assumed that i could loop through an enum and pass an instance of it to a function that takes the enum as parameter.

However, it seems that `let color in Colors` produced `color` of type string instead of type `Colors`.  Am I missing a cast somewhere?  Why doesn't enum loop produce a value of said Enum?

```
enum Colors {
    Red = "Red",
    Green = "Green",
    Yellow = "Yellow"
}

for (let color in Colors) {
  doStuff(color);
}

function doStuff(mycolor: Colors) {
  console.log(mycolor)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Object.values as for loop just treats it as iterating over an object

```
enum Colors {
  Red = "Red",
  Green = "Green",
  Yellow = "Yellow"
}

function doStuff(mycolor: Colors): void {
  console.log(mycolor);
}

Object.values(Colors).forEach(color => doStuff(color));
```

I guess Colours are only the values and not the enum entries, as you can use this too:

```
Object.entries(Colors).forEach((color: [string, Colors]) => doStuff(color[1]));
```

Also bear in mind that *for loops* generally are not good for things that don't have `if` or `switch` statement. Interestingly if you do add deeper logic to the for loop, TypeScript does determine the type:

```
for (const color in Colors) {
  if (color === Colors.Green) { 
    // Now the cat is either dead or alive 
    doStuff(color);
  }
}
```

Object.entries is still new so ensure that your `tsconfig.json` is referencing `es2017` as an entry for `compilerOptions/lib`.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I will edit the answer to include this

Comment: To really get the value of TS enable compilerOptions/strict: true as well.

Comment: Well, that opened a [can of worms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582837/how-to-read-an-element-with-compiler-option-set-to-strict).

Comment: Excellent. I'd like to add one small thing. in tsconfig.json, it's necessary to add es2017 to compilerOptions/lib entry.