# How to read an element with compiler option set to strict?

Tags: typescript

Consider the code below.  If I set `compilerOptions/strict` to `true`, Typescript complains that null is not assignable to HTMLElement.

```
let injectionElement: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("foo");
```

Is there a better way to do this (without resorting to the use of `any`).

Comment: Well, would this work? `let injectionElement: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("foo");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add entry option `dom` to you compilerOptions/lib

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"]....
```

The option `strict:true` enables all the strict type checking options of TypeScript allowing you to be much more clear on what methods take and what they return to bring clarity to your logic.

The specific rule you are caught by right now is `strictNullChecks` which shows an error when a variable has a possibility of not holding the expected value but its case is not handled.

Currently you are not handling the case where the `id` passed to `getElementById` turns out to be something that doesn't match any element:

```
function yourMethod(id: string): HTMLElement {
  // getElementById might return HTMLElement or null 
  // depending on whether the Id was found or not
  const injectionElement = document.getElementById(id);
  // now check you actually got something
  if (injectionElement) {
    return injectionElement;
  }
  // otherwise fail and tell the user their
  // id didn't return anything (Fail fast & fail often)
  // or other method of handling based on your 
  // context
  throw new Error(`Invalid element Id: ${id}`)
}
```

So basically the real type of `injectionElement` is the return type of `getElementById` function which is `HTMLElement | null` and not just `HTMLElement`

```
const injectionElement: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById("foo");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two general ways to handle this.

First, if you know prematurely that the element will be found (for example, if it was created by the same class), you can simply make a [non-null assertion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator):

```
let injectionElement: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("foo")!;
```

Note the exclamation mark at the end of the statement: it essentially says "I know that this is not null/undefined".

Second, if you can't be sure (and usually you can't), you must perform a runtime check, using the Ali's answer or some other way, and only then assign the result to the variable of non-nullable type.